# error during creation efs-server and mounting it for the AWS EKS setup

Tags: terraform, amazon-efs

i was trying to create a efs server and mount and facing some error there. Below is the code which i am using -

```
variable "subnets_nodes" {}
variable "security_group_nodes" {}
resource "aws_efs_mount_target" "efs-mt" {
   count = length(var.subnets_nodes)
   file_system_id  = aws_efs_file_system.efs.id
   subnet_id = "${var.subnets_nodes[count.index].id}"
   security_groups = ["${var.security_group_nodes.id}"]
 }
```

Error that i am getting is -

```
Error: Invalid index

  on ../modules/ops_bootstrap/modules/fluentd/main.tf line 44, in resource "aws_efs_mount_target" "efs-mt":
  44:    subnet_id = var.subnets_nodes[count.index].id
    |----------------
    | count.index is 1
    | var.subnets_nodes is object with 3 attributes

The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
```

```
Error: Invalid index

  on ../modules/ops_bootstrap/modules/fluentd/main.tf line 44, in resource "aws_efs_mount_target" "efs-mt":
  44:    subnet_id = var.subnets_nodes[count.index].id
    |----------------
    | count.index is 0
    | var.subnets_nodes is object with 3 attributes

The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
```

```
Error: Invalid index

  on ../modules/ops_bootstrap/modules/fluentd/main.tf line 44, in resource "aws_efs_mount_target" "efs-mt":
  44:    subnet_id = var.subnets_nodes[count.index].id
    |----------------
    | count.index is 2
    | var.subnets_nodes is object with 3 attributes
```

The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
any help will be appreciated ? (edited)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable `subnet_nodes`, is in the format of an `object` which cannot be accessed by an index. Objects and maps use key-value pairings rather than indices to reference elements. I presume the variable is something like:

```
subnets_nodes = {
  node_1 = {
    id = "some-id"
  }
  node_2 = {
    id = "some-id"
  }
  node_3 = {
    id = "some-id"
  }
}
```

So the first `id` in this example would be accessed by `var.subnets_nodes["node_1"].id`, not `var.subnets_nodes[0].id`.

It is recommended to use [for_each](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/for_each.html) for this use case, as it will iterate through the objects, where you can access the values using `each.value`.
This is preferred over the use of `count` as if the order of values changes when using `count`, resources will be forced to recreate. This is not an issue with `for_each`. ([An article](https://medium.com/@business_99069/terraform-count-vs-for-each-b7ada2c0b186) explaining this)

So you would want to do something like this:

```
resource "aws_efs_mount_target" "efs-mt" {
   for_each = var.subnets_nodes
   file_system_id  = aws_efs_file_system.efs.id
   subnet_id = each.value.id
   security_groups = ["${var.security_group_nodes.id}"]
 }
```

Comment: thnks and this worked and now i got what i was doing wrong.
One more doubt the efs that got created by this is not having any name. Any idea how to name it ?

i guess we dont have the "name" attribute for this to name it on the fly with terraform ? Any help here